# Get ERC20 Token amounts decimal value without web3 or ethersjs library

Tags: web3js, etherscan

Im wondering how can I format the token transferred value of a transaction to its correct decimal value?

Example values:
value: 1000000000000
decimal: 9

How can I make this appear as a decimal number without using something like ethers.utils.parseUnit ?

Comment: Something like `value / 10^decimal` is not working for you?

Comment: I have value / Math.pow(10, decimals) which seems to work but Im not sure if this has any  downsides for unexpected cases

Comment: I think it's fine.